# Check hierarchy of result set to modify 'case' condition

Tags: sql, oracle

QUERY EXECUTED:

```
case when type in ('A','B','C') then 0
else 1
end


RESULT:

ID, PARENT, TYPE
1        null         [result 1]
2   1       A     [result 0]
3   1       A     [result 0]
```

As per above implementation, 0 is the result for rows with ID 2 and 3.
However, ID 1 , which is the parent of 2,3 is being set as 1 as value of column 'TYPE' is null

I want to be able to check that:
If TYPE is empty but another row in the same hierarchy has TYPE populated with the value A/B/C then 0 must be set

Expected Result: Row with ID =1 must be set as 0 and not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table name is `tab`you have todo something like the following:

```
CASE WHEN TYPE IS NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab t2 
                                    WHERE t2.parent = t1.id
                                      AND t2.TYPE IN ('A','B','C'))
     THEN 0                                       
     WHEN TYPE IN ('A','B','C') 
     THEN 0
     ELSE 1
END
FROM tab t1
```

It's more or less exactly what you've described, just as code. If it happens in your data that you can have multiple instances in your data that have type null, for example:

```
ID  PARENT  TYPE
================
1   NULL    NULL
2   1       NULL
3   2       A
4   2       C
```

Then you have to use a hierarchical subquery:

```
SELECT id
     , parent 
     , CASE WHEN TYPE IS NULL 
            THEN NVL((SELECT MIN(NVL2(TYPE,0,1)) -- If there is a child with TYPE in ('A','B','C') this will return 0
                        FROM tab t2
                       START WITH t2.parent = 1
                              AND (t2.TYPE IS NULL OR t2.TYPE IN ('A','B','C'))
                       CONNECT BY t2.parent = PRIOR t2.id
                              AND (t2.TYPE IS NULL OR t2.TYPE IN ('A','B','C')))
                    ,1) 
            WHEN TYPE IN ('A','B','C') 
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END
FROM tab t1
```

Comment: Hello @Radagast81,
Would you help clarify the section:
(SELECT 1 FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.parent = t1.id AND t2.TYPE IN ('A','B','C')) 

As I understand, are you trying to check for 1 matching scenario where you are checking for parent and type in ('A','B','C') ?